# Passing values between promotions in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins job with two promotions steps.  The first promotion creates a Jira ticket.  The 2nd promotion needs to close the Jira ticket created in the first promotion.  How can I pass the Jira ticket information (ie key/id) from the first promotion to the second promotion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the **Copy files back to the job's workspace on the master node** plugin in the first promotion step, and then use the **Copy artifacts from another project** plugin in the second promotion step to get those files.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the following contains the information you're after:

- ☑ Promote builds when...

  - Promotion process

    - **Actions**

      - <kbd>Add action</kbd>

        - JIRA: Add related environment variables to build → [image]

          > Extracts JIRA information for the build to environment variables.
          >   Available variables:
          >
          > - JIRA_ISSUES - A comma separated list of issues which are referenced in the version control system changelog